# iPod Touch Not Showing Under Devices in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, ipod

I'm a software developer that recently switched to a Mac. I am using OS X 10.8.2. I am trying to debug an issue with a website using an iPod touch. I've been told that I can connect the iPod to my Mac mini via USB and use the Safari development tools to debug on the iPod. However, I haven't even gotten this far, as when I connect my iPod it does not show under devices in Finder. Could anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPod won't appear under Devices in the Finder, so you're not doing anything wrong.

1. In Safari on the Mac, first enable the Develop menu by going to Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar
2. Plug the iPod in over USB and launch Safari (on the iPod)
3. Back on the Mac, go to Safari's Develop menu and you'll have a new menu item for your iPod touch, which lists all of its open Safari tabs in a submenu
4. Select a tab from that submenu and Safari's Web Inspector will open. You can now debug the page on the iPod touch through the Web Inspector on the Mac

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Xcode? The best method for viewing error logs, etc....  iPod touches will not show up in Finder as their files are not visible.

Comment: CajunLuke, why do you keep editing my answers?